# Parallelizing deserialization step

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

There is the following pipeline:

1. item is produced (the producer is external to the pipeline);
2. item is deserialized (JSON to Java object);
3. item is processed;

At the moment it all happens synchronously in a single thread:

```
while(producer.next()) {
   var item = gson.deserialize(producer.item());
   
   processItem(item);
}
```

Or schematically:

```
PRODUCER -> DESERIALIZATION -> CONSUMER

(sync)      (sync)            (sync)
```

**The concern** is that the deserialization step has no side-effects and could be parallelized saving some world time.

The overall code should like the following:

```
var pipeline = new Pipeline<Item>();
pipeline.setProducer(producer);
pipeline.setDeserialization(gson::deserialize);
pipeline.setConsumer(item -> {
    ...
});
pipeline.run();
```

Or schematically:

```
         -> DESERIALIZATION
         -> DESERIALIZATION
         -> DESERIALIZATION
PRODUCER -> ...             -> CONSUMER
         -> DESERIALIZATION
         -> DESERIALIZATION
         -> DESERIALIZATION

(sync)      (parallel)         (sync)
```

**Important notice.** *Deserialized items* should be produced:

- synchronously;
- in the same order the original producer produces encoded items.

**Q.** Is there a standardized way to code such a pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
while(producer.next()) {
   CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> gson.deserialize(producer.item()))
    .thenRunAsync(item->processItem(item));
}
```

Comment: Definitely will give it a try. Does it preserve the original order?

Comment: This will essentially run the different steps concurrently on different items, but it won't guarantee that the 'processItem()' step happens on items in the same order that the items are supplied.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can achieve your pattern is to:

- Construct a multi-threaded executor to process the decoding requests
- Have a consumer queue; each time you submit an item to be decoded, also add the corresponding Future object to the consumer queue
- Have a consumer thread sit waiting to take items off the queue [which therefore consumes them in the order they were posted], call the corresponding get() method [which waits for the item to be decoded]

So the 'consumer' would look like this:

```
BlockingQueue<Future<Item>> consumerQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
Thread consumerThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Future<Item> item = consumerQueue.take();
                try {
                    // Get the next decoded item that's ready
                    Item decodedItem = item.get();
                    // 'Consume' the item
                    ...
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException irr) {

        }
    });
    consumerThread.start()
```

Meanwhile, the 'producer' end, with its multi-threaded 'decoder', would look like this:

```
ExecutorService decoder = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
while (!producer.hasNext()) {
        Item item = producer.next()

        // Submit the decode job for asynchronous processing
        Future<Item> p = decoder.submit(() -> {
            item.decode();
        }, item);

        // Also queue this decode job for future consumption once complete
        consumerQueue.add(p);
    }
```

As a separate matter, I wonder if you will actually see much benefit in practice, since by insisting on consumption in the same order, you are inherently introducing a serial condition on the process. But technically, this is one way that you could achieve what you are after.

P.S. If you didn't want a separate consumer thread, then the same 'producer' thread could poll the queue for completed items and execute in line.

Comment: A neat and beautiful solution. Will give it a try. Keeping the original order is a key challenge to the task. Otherwise, it's relatively easy to solve :)